# X-server for Windows CE

Tags: windows-mobile, x11, xorg, xserver

I'm trying to run an app from a remote X session (Ubuntu, 9.04) on a handheld device powered by Windows Mobile. I want to do this by running an X-server of some description on the mobile device and using SSH/PocketPuTTY or similar for a tunnel, as you'd do it on a standard PC/Mac.

Can anyone point me in the direction of some X servers for Windows Mobile, if they exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that [MI/X](http://www.microimages.com/mix/) will run on Windows Mobile.

Comment: That's good stuff - I can't find a download link for WM though...?

Answer (score 1):

I find your question is a little ambiguous. Do you want to run an app on windows CE and have the output on Ubuntu, or the other way around? In either case, I've never been able to find an X server for windows CE (I've wanted to do something very similar in the past). X servers tend to be rather resource hungry beasts.

The only alternative I can think of is to use something like VNC to achieve a similar result.

Comment: Heh, apologies for the ambiguity. The app is to run on the Linux server with the UI displayed on the handheld device. I've found an X server for Linux, called "Xfree for Windows CE" but haven't gotten it working yet.

Comment: hmmmm. That's a tricky one. If you can't get your server going perhaps something like VNC might help.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of diverting discussion away from your original question, have you considered simply running a VNC client on your mobile device, and using the built-in Ubuntu desktop sharing tools to connect to the server?

Generally, VNC degrades much more gracefully when faced with an unreliable network link (a common problem with handhelds), and most clients have support for panning and scaling the virtual desktop to allow a client with a small display to effectively interact with arbitrarily large screen resources.